# Eigenvalues of $A:\;A^2 +2A=0$

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors

> Let $A_n$ be square matrix where $n \geq 2$ and $A^2 +2A=0$. Then
>
> 1. A is singular
> 2. A is nonsingular
> 3. 0 and -2 are eigenvalues of A
> 4. either 0, or -2 is not an eigenvalue of A
> 5. (1)-(4) are false.

My attempt: thanks to Cayley-Hamilton theorem, we know that characteristic polynomial of A equal zero. Replacing A with $\lambda$ gives $\lambda^2 + 2\lambda = 0$. Hence, 0 and -2 are eigenvalues of A, i.e. (3).

There are 2 problems: 1st, the answer should be (5), and
2nd problem is that assuming that (3) is true, (1) is also must be true due to 0 eigenvalue. So, I made mistake somewhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The fact that $A^2 + 2A = 0$ implies that the **minimal** polynomial of $A$ **divides** $\lambda^2 + 2\lambda$. So the options for the minimal polynomial are $p_1(\lambda) = \lambda^2 + 2\lambda$, $p_2(\lambda) = \lambda$ and $p_3(\lambda) = \lambda + 2$. If the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $p_2$ then $A = 0$ (and so the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $0$) and if the minimal polynomial is $p_3$ then $A = -2I$ (and so the only eigenvalue of $A$ is $-2$).

If the minimal polynomial of $A$ is $p_1$ then since the minimal polynomial and the characteristic polynomial have the same roots it implies that the eigenvalues of $A$ are $0$ and $2$.

Using $A = -2I$, $A = 0$ and $A = \mathrm{diag}(0,-2)$, you see that the only possible answer is $5$.

Comment: Aha, so Cayley-Hamilton theorem works only in one direction, not in the direction I used it?

Comment: Indeed. The Cayley-Hamilton theorem says that if you plug $A$ into the characteristic polynomial, you get $0$ (the zero matrix). If you have some polynomial $p$ such that $p(A) = 0$, it doesn't mean that $p$ is the characteristic polynomial.

Comment: Thank you for such elaborate answer.

Comment: You're welcome.

Answer (score 3):

$A=0$ rules out a couple of the answers.  Can you find a non-singular matrix that satisfies $A^2+2A=0$?

Comment: For example, $diag(-2,-2)$

Comment: But what went wrong in my solution?